Where in Google Cloud console are the credentials to initialize Firebase in my webapp?
I want to link up Google Cloud Firebase to my web app. In this tutorial, I see these seven arguments passed to initializeApp. The narrator says they are available in the Google Cloud Console:

My question is, um, where in the console? I just don't see it:

Where am I supposed to be looking? Or is there a CLI command to reveal these arguments?

What you're looking for is not in the GCP console at all.  It's in the Firebase console for the same GCP project.  I suggest reviewing the documentation for getting started.  If you're working with an existing GCP project that hasn't had Firebase services added to it yet, you need to do that from the Firebase console in order to get anything working.

It's very confusing.
Firebase is a Google acquisition and though well-integrated, there remain differences.
The Google Cloud console: https://console.cloud.google.com
The Firebase console: https://console.firebase.google.com
You want to select "Project settings":

And the values you need are presented on that page.

I was today years old when I learned that there is a completely separate firestore console from the firebase view in the firebase console. Great answer!

I'm confident you're far from alone! There are various other consoles:Apps Script; Search Console; Play Console; Dialogflow Consoles
